# Doctrine 1 strange behaviour about data filtering

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I experienced strange Doctrine 1 behaviour when i tryed to filter query by inner join.

Doctrine tryes to overload my inner joins filtering by condition "where id in (...ids which corresponds to my other conditions...)".
It looks like Doctrine execute my query, fetch root ids and adds this strange condition based on it.

This makes me big problem because sometimes it adds "where id IS NULL" condition which removes all data from result.

I realised by some attempts that this strange Doctrine bahaviour triggers one inner join which filters my data.

Does anybody knows why Doctrine adds this condition and what can i do to avoid it?

====== update ======

I did more research and found that this strange whereIn condition is triggered by using limit().

Comment: If you found the solution write it as an answer and accept it. This will help any future users who will have similar problem.

Comment: iam affraid this is Doctrine1 normal behaviour how to deal with limited results. I think its because of performance, but its buggy. I did workaround without one inner join (4 still remains in that query) and it deappeared..